# SignalR - adding hubs at runtime

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have a working SignalR application, my global.asax.cs does all the usual MapHubs() etc, and I'm using a custom IAssemblyLocator which also loads in-memory assemblies as well as referenced assemblies. The two hubs I have are created at runtime in in-memory assemblies, and this works fine - hubs can push messages to clients etc.

At some point after the application has started, I want to add another hub at run time which will sit in it's own in-memory assembly, and make it appear in the signalr/hubs/ file.

How do I do this?

Calling MapHubs again results in an error because I already have the route defined. Removing the route (which I've only managed to do using RouteTable.Routes.Remove(RouteTable.Routes[0]) so far, and obviously isn't ideal) doesn't seem to work.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the alternate syntax instead of using the static signalr/hubs file since it will never update:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy

Comment: Thanks for that, I will give that a go, but also I think the problem is that once I've loaded the new dll into memory, the signalr framework is unaware of it. Calling GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(<newhubname>)

Comment: doh premature send! Calling GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(<newhubname>) results in an exception, but if I manually enumerate though my list of assemblies and look at the types in each, I can see the new hub type in there

Comment: Take  a look at replacing this service https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/IHubDescriptorProvider.cs

Comment: Great that looks like the business. Where can I see the source code for the default IHubDescriptorProvider? I take it this code runs whenever I attempt to get a hub using GetHubContext? Also, if I'm using my own code here and not using the automatically generated proxy, does that mean I no longer need to call MapHubs?

Comment: Got this running fine, thanks! I've copied and modified ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.cs. It would be good to be able to inherit and override here, so I don't have to worry about missing stuff when SignalR is updated...

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but could you include some code with this answer, rather than just a link? This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014777/add-signalr-persistent-connection-at-runtime-self-host) is potentially being closed as a duplicate of this one, but I'm hesitant since this answer itself may be removed as NAA.

Comment: @Rob, although code will surely be usefull, i don't think the question you linked is duplicate. Hubs vs Persistant connections, Selfhost vs IIS. If i'm wrong, can you please explain me why?

Comment: @user1515791 It was flagged as a duplicate, I hadn't looked too far into it since this answer was link only anyway. If it's not a duplicate, that's fine, but the answer could still use a snippet to prevent link rot :)