# Add SignalR persistent connection at runtime (self host)

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

I'm trying to add a path for a persistent connection at runtime. I found an example using SignalR.Hosting.Self, Version=0.5.1.10822, which has the `Server` class. Using that class, it is possible to do this:

```
        server.MapConnection<PathOneConnection>("/Path1/");
        server.Start();
        server.MapConnection<PathTwoConnection>("/Path2/");
```

Which worked, so I began hopefully creating my solution - starting out by getting the nuget packages....

However the newer version of SignalR uses an IAppBuilder

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

to startup, which does not allow to add paths after

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://*:8080/");
```

(or at least, it seems to be ineffective, as it won't add anything)

Is there any way to register a new server endpoint, while running?

**EDIT**, since this was tagged as duplicate:

- It's running as a self-hosted enviroment
- It's about persistent connection - not hubs - so IHubDescriptorProvider will not be helpfull i'm afraid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR - adding hubs at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070378/signalr-adding-hubs-at-runtime)

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler Could you please explain how that answers my question, i don't see it. To elaborate: my question is about a persistent connection in a self-host enviroment. That question is about hubs in a IIS enviroment, the accepted answer links to a javascript proxy and the only usefull info i found was the code for IHubDescriptorProvider. I could be wrong ofcourse, but i cannot find info in there that answers my question.