# Signalr dynamically add hubs

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've already looked [SignalR - adding hubs at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070378/signalr-adding-hubs-at-runtime), and the accepted answer doesn't provide an actual sample of the solution.

I'm looking to scale an application, a chat application that leverages the power of signalr hubs. Each hub is a chat room, and as users connect to my website, I'd like to dynamically add signalr hubs (so the application can scale). Is this at all possible? - Or is a another approach to have one single hub that can route traffic to different segments of users (simulating different chat "rooms")?

Comment: Seems like [working with groups](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) would be easier.

Comment: Looks like that's just what I'm looking for! I can accept your answer as accepted if you post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know for this is to use Groups from SignalR. And if you want to scale it horizontal you could use a Redis.